# h1 tag won't update on webpage on basic reactjs file

Tags: reactjs, flask

I have a h1 tag that displays the word 'project' to the screen, it's literally just a blank webpage with the word 'project'. However if I change that h1 tag say to 'test' it doesn't update.

I've tried clearing my cache, hard refreshing, running npm install again and npm start, nothing will change it. Also tried displaying it in a div.

```
import React from 'react'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1>Test</h1>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
   }
}
```

I expect the h1 on the webpage to display the word 'Test' but it still displays the word 'Project'

Comment: It's hard to say what might be wrong without knowing more about your setup. Are you using CRA? Maybe you have run a build script with e.g. `npm run build` and you are just watching the latest manually built files in your browser?

Comment: If running CRA, it's possible you're seeing the results of the ServiceWorker, in which case you need to clear it from your browser.

This is what I use to clear buggy ServiceWorkers: `chrome://serviceworker-internals/`

Comment: I tried npm run build and I was getting webpack errors, looks like webpage wasn't installed properly. Installed it and it fixed my problem. However now I've gotta do npm build and npm start just to get any code updates to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

`React.Fragment` was introduced in react 16.2 version. Probably you are using an older version of react

Try using a div instead

```
import React from 'react'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div >
        <h1>Test</h1>
      </div >
    )
   }
}
```

Comment: can you share package.json and webpack.config details